# How do I show a sequence is strictly decreasing

Tags: sequences-and-series

We have 
$$f(x) = \frac{3^x}{5^x} +  \frac{4^x}{5^x} -1$$
I need to show that it is strictly decreasing, how do I show this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint:  show the derivative  $f'$ is negative. ..

> So, $f'(x)= \left ( e^{xln {\frac 35}}+ e^{xln{\frac 45}}-1\right ) '=\ln\frac 35 \cdot (\frac 35)^x+\ln \frac 45 \cdot  (\frac45)^x\lt 0 , \forall x\in \mathbb R $. ..

Answer (score 2):

for constant  $0 < C < 1,$
$$ \frac{d}{dx} C^x = \frac{d}{dx} e^{x \log C} = C^x \log C < 0 $$

Answer (score 1):

Note that for $t>0$:
$$\left(\frac35\right)^x>\left(\frac35\right)^{x+t} \iff 1>\left(\frac35\right)^t \iff 5^t>3^t.$$